# How do you format and read randomly generated numbers in the console?

Tags: java

I've created a loop and random number generator that generates 100 numbers within the range of 1-100. I need to format these numbers so that it is 10 per line. I tried using printf and had a hard time. In addition, I have to find the average of all these numbers. The issue is I am unsure of how to do this because all the numbers are under the int variable 'randoms'. I can't add a single variable together and divide by 100.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int n = 100;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        int randoms = rand.nextInt(101);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to give the answer away (as it's more fun to find the answer for oneself!). Try to break the problem in small bits. Maybe the smallest is to print the number. If you start from there what is the smallest thing you need?

Comment: 10 per line, either use two loops or `%` mod expression within one loop, combine with `print` (in the same line) and `println` for a new line. Average of all numbers requires a new variable `int sum`, then divide by `n`.

Comment: Average  per row, col, all ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Note that we only handle one question at a time, and you need to be specific about the problem. Telling us "I tried using printf and had a hard time." is not helpful; we want to see the code you wrote that used `printf`, an explanation of what happened when you tried using that code, and an explanation of why that result is wrong or inadequate.

Comment: Computing an average is a separate question; yes, you won't be able to do that after the fact, because you have *replaced* the `randoms` value each time through the loop. Please try to *think* about this more. How would you solve it if you had to use pencil and paper? I can think of two ways: either you would write down all the numbers ahead of time (can you think of a way to store multiple numbers in the same variable?); or you would add up the numbers *as you go*, dividing by the count of numbers at the end (you know how many numbers there were, because you decided `n` ahead of time).

Comment: But either way, you cannot ask that in the same Stack Overflow question.

Comment: If you’ve already got the random numbers, your question is about formatting and averaging. The `random` tag doesn’t apply.

Comment: Perhaps an array would be useful for storing multiple numbers in the same variable. Thank you for your input, I'll be sure to check out the "How to Ask" for the future!

Answer (score 1):

You may print each number without a new line, and with spaces before to pad at 4-length string, and each 10 values, print a new line. For the average, use math : `sum/count`

```
Random rand = new Random();
int n = 100;
int total = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    int randoms = rand.nextInt(101);
    total += randoms;
    System.out.format("%4d", randoms);
    if (i % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
System.out.println("AVG " + total / (double) n);
```

```
  49  55  89  26  88  58  80  98  62   8
  34  65   9   3  28  71  30  11  50  50
  18  90  61  62  18  93  83  83  57  14
   9  54  49   6  24  28  60   8  86  83
  60   6  17  67  49  89  66  13  65  50
  70  24   3  90  89   4  47  49  48   7
  16  38  79  59  51   9  22  81   8  84
  52  30  64  97  42 100  30  26  66  44
  22  46  16 100  73 100  56  63   8  48
  50  88  55  93   6  82  65  46  44   7
AVG 49.29
```